# Cordova erro build

Tags: apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá amigos sou novo no mundo cordova e estou tendo esse erro ao tentar gerar o app, esse é o meu primeiro app não cheguei nem a mexer na pasta www.

se poderem me ajudar fico muito grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problema resolvido só precisava baixar os drivers do android 7